# Form gets focused when I add a control

Tags: c#, winforms

Im programatically adding controls to one of five panels in a form every 10 seconds. When all 5 panels are filled I clean the first one and add my new control in there and so on.

Now everytime I add a new control my form gets focused and the application I'm working is loses focus.

How can I prevent my form from beeing focused?

//EDIT
I found out that the last focused control (in my case a button) gets the focus upon the new created control, but I still dont know how to give my previous application the focus again

Code:

```
        System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x => {
            if (!startStopBool) return;
            if (controlIdx == 5) controlIdx = 0;
            {
                if (controlArray[controlIdx] != null)
                {
                    DisposeControl(controlArray[controlIdx]);
                }
                controlArray[controlIdx] = AddControl(controlIdx);
                controlIdx++;
            }
        }, null, 0, 10000);
```

after adding the control in the AddControl-function (a WebBrowser) the last used control from my form (the button) steals the focus

Comment: Can you show minimal code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Ill try to add some parts

Comment: Not sure, but there is a method called `Focus()` from `Control`, you could try to call it.

Comment: Oh I think we misunderstood, I do not want my Form to get the Focus, I want to prevent that

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the application I'm working".  Is this part of your WinForm project (so, another form)?  Or, is this some completely separate application outside of your project (ie, excel or something else)?

Comment: Completly separate, I think the problem is with the WebBrowserControl. Upon navigating it seems to take the focus. Even if I minimize the form the focus is lost on my other application, whatever that might be (a game, a browser, anything)